# How to use the AWS CLI to enable Console access for a User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have a script which creates a user-profile and sets a console password using IAM via the AWS CLI.

However, this does not seem to actually enable console access, which I then have to do through GUI.

I've tried to find a way to do this via the CLI (including policies, groups, and roles), but can't find anything.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `aws iam create-login-profile --user-name alice --password sprin123 --password-reset-required`

It *does* enable Console access. If it doesn't for you, please provide more information.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/create-login-profile.html

Comment: That was exactly what I was doing.  But the account still had no console access.
There's not much to say, beyond I run that command, and it doesn't unlock.

Comment: So what happens when you try to log in using the credentials that you created?